# PHP SQL Temporary table won't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to understand how the temporary tables work. But even when I copy and paste it from my tutorials, I don't get the expected result.

See the code underneath for more info.
At the moment the .php file returns a blank page (no errors),
while i would expect it to be:

> 1 Row inserted.

I looked for the error code but found out that temporary tables don't have an error code.

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx","xxx");

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myCity (Name CHAR(30)");

    $city = "'s Hertogenbosch";
    $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $city);

    /* this query with escaped $city will work */
    if (mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO myCity (Name) VALUES ('$city')")) 
    {
        printf("%d Row inserted.\n", mysqli_affected_rows($link));
    }

    mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: You'd be way, way more successful if you read the tutorials fully and used `echo mysqli_error();` when your mysql queries fail, which is what's happening. Anyway, to cut down your problem - you have column `Name`. That is a reserved word in MySQL. Rename that column to anything else or use ` to quote it.

Comment: I don't work with php or mysql, but I would look for another way to test my work.  Specifically, after the insert query, I would run a select query and output the results.  In fact, you don't even have to do the insert.  Once you create the table, do a select count(*) and output the results.

Comment: [**Read up on the subject**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-temporary-tables.htm) if you haven't already done so. May give you an idea as to what may be happening.

Comment: `Name` is not a reserved word, [**have a look**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) @N.B.

Comment: @Fred-ii- - thanks, I rushed without checking with docs, it's not a reserved word.

Comment: @N.B. and changing the Name wasnt the solution.

Comment: @N.B. No problemo. However `RENAME` is, so you weren't far off ;-)

Comment: Just do this `mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myCity (Name CHAR(30))");` @user2955526

Comment: Welcome fore what? Your wrong answer, and than to say i'm to lazy to use your wrong answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works for me

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors",1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "admin123", "test");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$mysqli->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE CITIES (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(64) NOT NULL
)");

//$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO CITIES VALUES ('1', 'Bavaria')");
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO CITIES VALUES ('2', 'Havana')");

//$mysqli->commit();

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM CITIES LIMIT 10")) {
    printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);
    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}

//$mysqli->query("DROP TABLE CITIES");

$mysqli->close();
```

Remember Temporary tables only exist by session, sometimes we need create conventional table and truncate later...
You would must think use DB lib like Doctrine DBAL or ADODb or something like that...

Comment: Thank you alvk4r! Worked like an angel!

Comment: looked up the meaning of the existence (session based), this is just what i needed.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have an error in your sql creation. You are missing a closing parenthesis: ")"

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myCity (Name CHAR(30)
```

Adrien.

Comment: Hey Adrien M.,

Don't really follow, current code=

mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myCity (Name CHAR(30)");

And you are saying:

mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myCity (Name CHAR(30)")"; ????

Comment: That's what he's saying.  Look at the part of that command in your question.  It's either a mistake in your code or a mistake in your question.

Comment: He didn't fix it for you, he just showed you the place where you made the mistake. It's up to you to figure out that you need to add one more ) so it works.

Comment: The OP was obviously looking for something he/she could simply drag the mouse to copy/paste, as a ready-made and ready-to-go piece code. "**Typing/adding"** a simple `)` was probably just too much; are people that lazy? Never mind, I think I answered my own question. `+1` for you Adrien, cheers. @user2955526 This was a simple debugging issue. You won't go far in the coding world if you don't learn how to debug your code. Good luck, you'll need it.

Comment: Ok this is the second time that people are being this rude. Im trying to understand PHP. I know your not obligated to help me, but neither are you obligated to answer. If we look at my code, something is wrong, what, I simply don't know. I changed the name, it wouldn't help. I changed the wrong syntax, still wrong. So yes i'm more happy with someone helping me the right way than some1 giving me the wrong answers. And last but not least, this is a test, see my  1 post, so copy and paste will not work.

Comment: Had you looked [**at my comment**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837230/php-sql-temporary-table-wont-work#comment29499742_19837230) you would have been well on your way. [**You pasted**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837230/php-sql-temporary-table-wont-work#comment29499426_19837465) what you thought was correct. You weren't far off though. **Comments** can be just as useful as answers. Plus you didn't [**read up on the subject**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-temporary-tables.htm) *obviously.*  @user2955526

Comment: yup looked at your comment, and no it didn't work. If we look at your "read up" wich I obviously didn't read, we can see that there is just 1 ")" and not 2.

Comment: I said ***"on your WAY"*** - I never said it would totally fix your (other) problems. It's up to you to figure out "Where" (else) you went wrong and not have somebody simply take a piece of code from the Web and pasted it. If you do happen to post another question (in the future), come back with a "real" problem. @user2955526

Comment: Suddenly out of the attack and into defensing, please let my daughter do that, hahahaha.  Have a nice day, looks like you need it. (p.s. this is not aligning with ""Typing/adding" a simple ) was probably just too much; are people that lazy? ")